# Teams tab application returns SSO error in mobile Outlook

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We've built a Teams tab app following pretty much this sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/dev/hello-world-tab-with-backend

It is working fine on all platforms (Teams Web, Teams Desktop, Teams Mobile, Outlook Web, Outlook Desktop) except Outlook Mobile. It seems that outlook mobile is not getting sso token from:

```
import { useTeamsUserCredential } from '@microsoft/teamsfx-react';
```

We're getting this on Outlook Mobile:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up7Xf.jpg)

My understanding is that the Auth flow should work exactly same on all platforms